# 'of' from Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I was doing [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) tutorial on reactive forms and stumbled on following problem:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

here you should import of from rxjs but when I try to it say's:

> [ts] Module '"/.../node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported
>   member 'of'.

Also tried

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

which didn't work either.

In the example 'of' is used for following:

```
 getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(heroes).pipe(delay(this.delayMs)); // simulate latency with delay
  }
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: what's your `rxjs` version

Comment: @Vikas ESM5 - I think this is the version

Comment: That's not your `rxjs` version kindly share your package.json

Comment: @Vikas thanks for the clarification - the version is "rxjs": "^5.5.6",

Comment: Observable.of(...) worked!

Comment: The tutorial uses Angular 6 and thus rxjs 6, where imports have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with RxJS 5. The syntax `of` is a feature of RxJS 6. Use `Observable.of` instead

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
        // or 
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return Observable.of(heroes).pipe(delay(this.delayMs)); // simulate latency with delay
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using rxjs 5 then try to import it as:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

And if you are using rxjs 6 then pass it like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/create';
```