# Ionic - TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.of is not a function on mac

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, rxjs

I have created a new super ionic starter template. But I am facing the following issue in windows and mac. However, the app is running perfectly fine in ubuntu.

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.of is not a function on mac
```

I did research about the issue but didn't find any solution.

Comment: use `of` instead of `Observable.of`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50428188/5695162